# Using init function after constructor vs initializing in constructor - JAVA

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

What is the difference between

```
public UserBean() {
        // create the session state
        state = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);

}
```

and

```
public UserBean() {
        init();
}

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // create the session state
        state = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);            
    }
```

where state is one of the many attributes of the class.

Comment: State will be instantiated when the UserBean is instantiated. In other case, UserBean will be instantiated and then the state will get instantiated.

Comment: first one exact after building of new instance initialize ``state``, second one after initialization call method ``init``(which initialize ``state``) and again call ``init`` method when fired event post construct. ``@PostConstruct`` fired when all context for bean initialized.

Comment: Calling an overridable method in a constructor should not be done (make it final). Here it also is not needed because of @PostConstruct. The link of the prior comment says the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the `@PostConstruct` annotation.
A method annotated with  should be invoked by the container after dependency injection was performed. **It has not** to be invoked by your applicative code.

So of course using `@PostConstruct` without container (EJB, Spring, Guice...) makes no sense.

The `@PostConstruct` doc states :

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be
>   executed after dependency injection is done to perform any
>   initialization.

To summarize  :

- the container creates the bean by invoking the constructor
- the container sets the bean dependencies
- the `@PostConstruct` method is invoked

Note that between the steps 1, 2 and 3, the container may perform other tasks for other beans but you should not worry about that as the javadoc also states that `@PostConstruct` method MUST be invoked before the class is put into service.

Comment: I am working with jsf2 and using tomcat. So does tomcat takes care of @postConstruct?

Comment: Tomcat alone, no. It is not a component container. It is a servlet container. If you add Spring as component container in your app, Spring will take care of it.

Comment: But it is in jsf 2.2 code. Are you saying there is nothing in jsf to take care of it? i thought jsf was an alternative to spring.

Comment: About managed beans of JSF2, no idea. On the internet, we could read that yes. So give it a go.